# Verify proof that $f:X\to Y$ a homeomorphism implies $f_*:H_p(X)\to H_p(Y)$ is an isomorphism

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-verification, homological-algebra

I have to prove that

> $f:X\to Y$ a homeomorphism implies $f_*:H_p(X)\to H_p(Y)$ is an isomorphism for all $p$

Where $H_p(X)$ is the $p$th homology group of $X$. To me this seems to come down to proving that the induced function $F_\# :S_p(X)\to S_p(Y)$ is an isomorphism, for $f_*$ is induced by $f_\#$ where it is clear that if $f_\#$ is an isomorphism then $f_*$ is too.

And this is easy, since we know that

$$(id_X)_\#=(f^{-1}\circ f)_{\#}=(f^{-1})_\#\circ f_\#$$
And the other way around, so that $(f^{-1})_\#=(f_\#)^{-1}$ showing that $f_\#$ is an isomorphism.

Now I'm very new to homology so I'm very much unsure about the correctness of this reasoning, so any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks correct. But now you need to know that $f_#$ induces the an iso on homolgy. You also could do the same thing with $f_*$ and show it directly.

Comment: Do you know what a functor is? Functors preserve isomorphisms. Homology is a functor.